# Change mail item within the Application_NewMail Event

Tags: vba, outlook

I overwrite the Application_NewMail() function, in order to do something with the incoming mail.

If the incoming mail matches given condition, then I want to do olMail.Subject = "Mymark" + olMail.Subject or I do olMail.Categories = "MyMark".

But it seems that I do this too late, because the mail is already in inbox and theese changes are not propagated.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
Dim olFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set olFld = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
olFld.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False   
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olFld.Items.GetLast
Dim Reg1 As RegExp
Dim M1 As MatchCollection
Dim M As Match
Dim doc As Variant
Set olMail = olFld.Items.GetLast        
Set Reg1 = New RegExp
With Reg1       
    .Pattern = "[^0] (x ERROR)"
    .Global = True
End With 
If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then
    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
    For Each M In M1
          olMail.Subject    = "mymark" + olMail.Subject
          olMail.Categories = "XYZ"             
    Next
End If      
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: I added my code above.

Comment: You should first provide an appropriate subject to prove the RegEx works but it is likely `oMail.Save`.

Comment: @niton oMail.Save was the solution, but I don't understand what do you mean with: 'You should first provide an appropriate subject to prove the RegEx works'

Comment: Simply a suggestion of what is needed for a complete question. An example subject in the question would have proved RegEx was not the source of the problem. I had to assume the RegEx was good.

Answer (score 2):

*Work with [Application.NewMailEx event (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.NewMailEx)*

> *The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the NameSpace.GetItemFromID method and process the item.*

*Example in a class module*

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

    Dim Item As Object
    Set Item = Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
        Item.Subject = "mymark " & Item.Subject
        Item.Save
        
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
    
End Sub
```