# Recognize pattern for categorizing mails then move mail to folders that are created if needed

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I developed a email-filtering VBA code, so I can recognize the pattern [ABC] for categorizing mails.

I expect incoming mails to be moved to folders and categorized.

The folders are to be created if needed.

Target :

extract words within [this Bracket], and specific code such as CMX , INC

> Subject : `[ABC]`      --> create inbox folder `ABC`
>
> Subject : `[CMX]`      --> create inbox folder `ABC`
>
> Subject : `CMX`      --> create inbox folder `CMX`
>
> Subject : `INC000000156156`      --> create inbox folder `INC` and sub-folder  `INC000000156156`

The code does not create folders, especially when I delete the folder with mails.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    
    Dim olFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFld = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    olFld.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olFld.Items.GetFirst
    MyNiftyFilter olMail
End Sub

Private Sub MyNiftyFilter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Debug.Print Item
    Debug.Print Item.Subject
    
    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim RegExp As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim Pattern As String
    
    Dim Email_Subject As String
    Pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"
    Email_Subject = Item.Subject

    With RegExp
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = .Execute(Email_Subject)
    End With
    
    Dim olFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFld = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Matches(0)
            Debug.Print Matches(0).SubMatches(0)
            Set oloUtlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set ns = oloUtlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set itm = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set SubFolder = itm.Folders.Item(Matches(0).SubMatches(0))
            If SubFolder Is Nothing Then
                SubFolder = itm.Folders.Add(Matches(0).SubMatches(0))
            End If
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `If Action = ACT_DELIVER Then`? also you have set regex twice...

Comment: `Set GoodRegEx.Pattern = "(([\w-\s]*)\s*)"` does not look good

Comment: Why should the revised code should be ? Even though  I delete these two codes , I find new issues : invalid type at the first line of my sub function

Comment: If GoodRegEx.Pattern = "(([\w-\s]*)\s*) is not good, what is the revised practice or magic pattern to recogniss [ABC] and extract ABC within the bracket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try something like this*

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim olFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFld = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    olFld.Items.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olFld.Items.GetFirst
    MyNiftyFilter olMail
End Sub

Private Sub MyNiftyFilter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)


    Debug.Print Item
    Debug.Print Item.Subject

    Dim Matches As Variant
    Dim RegExp As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim Pattern As String
    Dim Email_Subject As String

    Pattern = "(([\w-\s]*)\s*)"

    Email_Subject = Item.Subject

    With RegExp
        .Global = False
        .Pattern = Pattern
        .IgnoreCase = True
    Set Matches = .Execute(Email_Subject)
    End With

        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print Matches(0) ' Print on Immediate Window 
        End If

    Set RegExp = Nothing
    Set Matches = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing

End Sub
```

*for the regex use  `\[(.*?)\]`*
*demo
https://regex101.com/r/U3bjOf/1

https://regex101.com/r/U3bjOf/2

[image]

```
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Matches(0) ' full match [ABC]
        Debug.Print Matches(0).submatches(0) ' submatch ABC
    End If
```

---

*to create sub-folder use function like this*

```
'//  Function - Check folder Exist
Private Function FolderExists(Inbox As MAPIFolder, FolderName As String)
    Dim Sub_Folder As MAPIFolder

    On Error GoTo Exit_Err
    Set Sub_Folder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)

    FolderExists = True
        Exit Function

Exit_Err:
    FolderExists = False

End Function
```

*then call it*

```
    Dim olFld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFld = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Dim FolderName As String

    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Matches(0) ' full match [ABC]
        Debug.Print Matches(0).submatches(0) ' submatch ABC

        FolderName = Matches(0).submatches(0)

        '// Check if folder exist else create one
        If FolderExists(Inbox, FolderName) = True Then
             Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(FolderName)
        Else
             Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders.Add(FolderName)
        End If

        Item.Move SubFolder
    End If
```

Comment: If Item.Class = olMail Then <---- this sentence says: Object Variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Do we need to declare what is olMail ?

Comment: Still, 
   Email_Subject = Item.Subject <---- this sentence says: Object Variable or with block variable not set

Comment: still not working since the error that  Object Variable or with block variable not set still  occurs at the line Items.Subject . That does not make sense. Have you ever check and test the code before you release to this reply ?

Comment: I find out that the Outlook.MailItem is nothing instead of real incoming emails

Comment: I am not sure whether this is relavant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080125/change-mail-item-within-the-application-newmail-event

Comment: with respect to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443172/categorisation-of-incoming-by-regex-arouse-application-newmail-byte-val-mism , how could I create sub folders ?